# Use same placeAutocomplete function to set value to two different textView

Tags: android

I have two different `textView`, one for Departure and Landing. When user quick any of the `textView` the google `PlaceAutoComplete` activity opens in a new window and the user picks the departure destination. For the Landing the same things happens. The problem is that I want to be able to set a different destination for each `textView`. Thanks for the Help.........

```
public void onClick(View v) {

  if (v == mDeparture) {
      openAutocompleteActivity();
  }

  if (v == mLanding) {
      openAutocompleteActivity();
   }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

            mDeparture.setText(place.getAddress());

        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {

            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}



private void openAutocompleteActivity() {

    try {
        Intent intent = newPlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                0 /* requestCode */).show();

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign two different flags, one for departure and one for landing. Like this

```
  int DEPARTURE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
  int LANDING_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mDeparture) {
      openAutocompleteActivity(DEPARTURE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    if (v == mLanding) {
      openAutocompleteActivity(LANDING_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
  }

private void openAutocompleteActivity(int mode) {

  try {
    Intent intent = newPlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
            .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, mode);
  } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
            0 /* requestCode */).show();

  } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);
  }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == DEPARTURE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

        mDeparture.setText(place.getAddress());

    } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {

        Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

    }
  }
  else if (requestCode == LANDING_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

        mLanding.setText(place.getAddress());

    } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {

        Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

    }
  }
}
```

Try this. You will be able to use single activity for selecting departure and landing both